# nginx (https) to tomcat (https)

Tags: tomcat, nginx, https

I'm having troubles getting a https nginx server to connect to a tomcat instance also using https. Nginx writes this to the error log:

```
2015/03/02 23:15:34 [error] 20074#0: *11 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8443/app/", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

The setup is like this:

```
browser -> nginx(https) -> tomcat(https) /app
```

with this result:

```
OK:   wget https://localhost:8443/app
FAIL: wget https://localhost/app
```

So I can get to the webapp going directly to tomcat https port but not proxied by nginx. The following is how I created the certs and setup tomcat and nginx.

Nginx

```
Create the private server key:
    sudo openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048

Create a certificate signing request (common name set to localhost):
    sudo openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr

Remove the password:
    sudo cp server.key server.key.org
    sudo openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key

Sign your SSL Certificate:
    sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

Edit nginx.conf to add this:
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate      server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  server.key;
        ssl_verify_client off;
        ssl_trusted_certificate tomcat.crt;
        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location / {        
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass      https://127.0.0.1:8443;
        }
    }
```

Tomcat

```
Create a local self-signed Certificate:
    keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore localhost.keystore

Edit server.xml config to add this:

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="localhost.keystore" 
           keystorePass="password0" proxyPort="443" proxyHost="localhost"/>
```

This was setup on a Mac with

- apache-tomcat-8.0.18
- nginx/1.7.10
- Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
- java 1.8.0_31

Doing the same setup on Windows 8.1 works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things were wrong:

Firstly I had what appears to be a faulty nginx build as I rebuilt from source with the latest ssl module and that corrected some errors.

Secondly, it's a bad idea trying to use localhost as the hostname on both nginx and tomcat if you have two different certificates created for each. Instead I added some FQDN for tomcat and nginx to /private/etc/hosts (on the Mac)

```
127.0.0.1    nginx.localhost.com tomcat.localhost.com
```

Then I recreated the certificates for both nginx and tomcat using a common name of 'nginx.localhost.com' for the nginx certificate and 'tomcat.localhost.com' for the tomcat certificate. Remembering in the tomcat steps to use 'tomcat.localhost.com' when prompted for First and last name (as this is actually the Common Name field which should be a host or ip address).

I deleted all the old localhost certs from the JRE cacerts and Mac's Keychains. Then started nginx and tomcat. Then using safari visit the urls https://nginx.localhost.com and https://tomcat.localhost.com. Safari pops up a certificate dialog, then click on show certificate, then expanded the Trust section of the certificate, then select "Always Trust" for "When using this certificate" option. Then click the trust the certificates button. This adds the two certs as trusted for the browser in Macs Keychain under the 'login' chain.

Now the browser was happy but I had two tomcat webapps talking to each other via nginx and they needed the two certs created to verify the ssl hostname they were connecting to so I added them to the Java cacerts file by doing this:

Get the tomcat and nginx server certs by running these commands

```
openssl s_client -connect tomcat.localhost.com:8443

openssl s_client -connect nginx.localhost.com:443
```

and copying the certificate written to screen starting with this tag '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----' and ending in this tag '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'

Then import these server certificates into the java cacerts file using this:

```
sudo keytool -import -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file tomcat.localhost.com -alias tomcat.localhost.com 

sudo keytool -import -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file nginx.localhost.com -alias nginx.localhost.com
```

Restart nginx and tomcat and everything now works.